# Understanding Tensorflow control dependencies

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, controls

I am trying to gain a stronger grasp of TensorFlow. I came across the concept of control dependencies. I understand that the order of ops as specified by us is not really relevant to Tensorflow during execution. In order to optimise the speed of execution TensorFlow decides its own order of calculating nodes. 
But we can customise order of execution by using tf.control_dependencies.
I am not able to understand the use cases of the function. Can anyone direct me to some resource(other than the documentation) or explain the working of this function?
An example:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.Variable(5)
y=tf.Variable(3)
assign = tf.assign(x,x+y)
z = x+assign
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   with tf.control_dependencies([assign]):
        z_out = sess.run(z)

print(z_out)
```

The output of the code is 8. So I infer that since z=x+y,the assign node has not been evaluated(right?). But doesn't this mean that the result of tensorflow may be erroneous? This means we need to create new nodes during every operation to force TensorFlow to calculate all the nodes leading up to the result. But in say training a neural network with 10000 steps if each step creates a new set of 1000 weights/parameters won't the space complexity explode?

Comment: [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) is not doing anything in that snippet. When you create a control dependencies context it affects the new operations created within it, but there are no new operations inside that block, just the evaluation of existing operations.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide an example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the snippet you have posted, [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) is not having any effect. The function creates a context where **new operations** are created with a control dependency to the given operations, but in your code there are no new operations within the context, just evaluation of previously existing operations.

In most cases, control flow in TensorFlow is "obvious", in the sense that there is only one way to make a computation correctly. However, when stateful objects (i.e. variables) are involved, there are situations that may be ambiguous. Consider the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(0)
v2 = tf.Variable(0)
upd1 = tf.assign(v1, v2 + 1)
upd2 = tf.assign(v2, v1 + 1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

`v1` and `v2` are both variables initialized to `0` and then updated. However, each use the value of the other variable in the update. In a regular Python program things would run sequentially, so `upd1` would run first (so `v1` would be `1`) and `upd2` after (so `v2` would be `2`, because `v1` was `1`). But TensorFlow does not record the order in which operations are created, only their dependencies. So it may also happen that `upd2` runs before `upd1` (so `v1` would be `2` and `v2` would be `1`) or that both update values (`v2 + 1` and `v1 + 1`) are computed before the assignments (so both `v1` and `v2` would be `1` in the end). Indeed, if I run it several times:

```
for i in range(10):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run([upd1, upd2])
        print(*sess.run([v1, v2]))
```

I do not always get the same result (personally I get `1 1` and `2 1`, although technically `1 2` would also be possible). If for example you wanted to compute the new value for `v2` after `v1` has been updated, you could just do the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(0)
v2 = tf.Variable(0)
upd1 = tf.assign(v1, v2 + 1)
upd2 = tf.assign(v2, upd1 + 1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Here the new value `v2` is computed using `upd1`, which is guaranteed to be the value of the variable after the update. So here `upd2` would have an implicit dependency to the assignment, and so things would work as expected.

But what if you wanted to always compute the new values for `v1` and `v2` using the non-updated variable values (that is, consistently end up with both `v1` and `v2` being `1`)? In that case you can use [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies):

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(0)
v2 = tf.Variable(0)
new_v1 = v2 + 1
new_v2 = v1 + 1
with tf.control_dependencies([new_v1, new_v2]):
    upd1 = tf.assign(v1, new_v1)
    upd2 = tf.assign(v2, new_v2)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Here, the assignment operations cannot happen until the new values for `v1` and `v2` have been computed, so their final values will always be `1` in both cases.

Comment: Thank you, I understood my misconception. But what if we were to execute the statements using multiple sess.run commands instead of a single sess.run([list])?  Also does every updation create a tensor like assign? Then won't running a large number of iterations cause memory wastage?

Comment: @pranav Control dependencies (and dependencies in general) are only relevant within the same call to `run`. Different calls to `run` do not share any information except for stateful objects (variables), that is, intermediate values are computed again from the beginning, even if they will be the same. Running update nodes (e.g. `sess.run(upd1)`) does not create new operations or tensors in the graph, it just runs the computation and changes the variable value.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: To me, it seems like `with tf.control_dependencies([new_v1, new_v2]):` is to make sure that new_v1 and new_v2 are computed first, then it computes what's inside the context: 
    `upd1 = tf.assign(v1, new_v1)`
    `upd2 = tf.assign(v2, new_v2)` . Am I correct?